# How to check if there was a crash with monkeyrunner

Tags: android, adb, monkeyrunner, android-monkey

I am going to implement smart monkey test with `monkeyrunner`.

Is there any way I can get crash information just like what `adb monkey`'s doing?

Even though `monkeyrunner` clicked crash-generating button, it doesn't generate crash information to `STDOUT` nor `STDERR`.